# Don't understand this piecewise continuous function declaration of a PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am preparing for a statistic exam and came across the following task:

Show that the function

$$
f(x):= \begin{cases}
    0 & \quad x < 1 \\
    \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} & \quad x \in [2^{n-1};2^n[ \quad  \text{for all} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$

is a PDF.

Sketch the graph in the range of [-5; 5] as well as the graph of the CDF. (Remark: this function
is an example of a piecewise continuous function that has only finite many jumps in every closed interval
and both right and left limits exists.

I can't understand the function definition. Is it constant with varying parameter n ?. So I can not even
sketch the graph of this function. Kindly help me understand the function's definition. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: Try finding some specific values of $f$, such as:  $f(.5)$, $f(1.3)$, $f(3.9)$, $f(22.6)$. See if that helps you get a feel for things.

Comment: It is constant on interval $(-\infty,1)$ and also on intervals $[1,2),[2,4),[4,8),\dots$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks @paw88789 and @drhab!

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand the definition of the function I try to show that it is a PDF by showing that the integral of $f(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$.

\begin{align}
F(x) = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \; \mathrm{d}x && \text{for a PDF integral must evaluate to 1}\\
= & \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \; \mathrm{d}x && \text{for x less than 1 it is 0} \\
= & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} \; \mathrm{d}x && \text{sum over all intervalls}\\
= & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}} \; x \Big|_{2^{n-1}}^{2^n} && \text{evaluate at interval boundaries}\\
= & \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n && \text{index shift}\\
= & \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n - 1 && \text{geometric series} \\
= & \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} -1 = 1 && \blacksquare
\end{align}

I would appreciate if someone could look over it and tell me if my derivation is corrector not. Thanks!

Comment: It is not really an index shift, just an extension of the series. You would need an index shift when equating to $\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$.